# how to run selenium script with real browser in jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I am running selenium scripts in Jenkins and it is showing console output without opening any real browser like Mozilla/Chrome/IE.

I want to run the scripts using a real browser and want to see what is happening UI.

> Is there any plug in need to install in Jenkins? or any code required to add? or any services need to modify/restart/any operation?

Please suggest me if there is any solution or any website providing the information. Thank you

Comment: are you wonking on windows?

Comment: yes exactly Shubham Jain

Comment: udpated my answer as war file URL

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using Jenkins window installer which is working as service in Windows. In Windows Services are not allowed for UI invocation/execution.

You need to use jenkins.war and run it using a cmd which is executed as "run as admin"

Download war from below URL :-

https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/war/

https://jenkins.io/download/

Use the following command at command prompt:

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090
```

If you want to use https use the following command:

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpsPort=9090
```

You can change the port number as per your need in above command

Now go to any browser and hit

```
localhost:9090
```

Comment: Yes you need to invoke jenkins from command line. and then hit URL as localhost:9090 in your browser. you will see the jenkins landing page

Answer (score 0):

You can try below steps to run selenium scripts on real browser in your local machine or any server that supports browser ... from Jenkins.

- Convert your selenium project to maven project.
- Add dependency for all the jars required in pom.xml
- Add plugins in pom

  ```
      <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
          <configuration>
              <source>1.7</source>
              <target>1.7</target>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.12</version>
          <inherited>true</inherited>
          <configuration>
              <suiteXmlFiles>
                  <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
              </suiteXmlFiles>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
  </plugins>
  ```
- Change run configuration--> under Test --> suite --> set location 0f testng.xml e.g :D:\\testng.xml
- Open Jenkins(for installing Jenkins, you can follow any thread to install Jenkins).
- Install maven plugin in Jenkins and create a maven project under BUILD input pom.xml path in ROOT POM  e.g :Root POM -- > D:\\pom.xml and under goals provide clean test.
- Save and click on Build Now :)